# How to define the interface for an array in react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a variable called `data`, which is an `array` that contains a `function` and an `object`. I want to define a model for this instead of using `any`, but unfortunately I don't know how, thank you for your help.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
interface data {
  // how do i write ?
  person: Person;
  handleShowPerson: () => void ;
}
export default function App() {
  const person: Person = { name: "nil", age: 30 };
  const handleShowPerson = ({ name, age }: person) => (
    <h1>
      My name is {name} and I am {age} years old`)
    </h1>
  );
  const data: data = [person, handleShowPerson];
}
```

Comment: Based on usage, that seems to be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), `person` and `handleShowPerson` are **not** properties of anything.

Comment: Now you don't know how I can define an interface for the data variable? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Why do you want to define it as an interface? You already have an interface that's going _in_ the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

As you want your data to be an array, you can do the following:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// First element of the array will be of type `Person`
// Second element will be a function that takes in `Person` as argument and returns JSX
// This sort of type definition is called a `Tuple` in typescript
type Data = [Person, (person: Person) => JSX.Element]

export default function App() {
  const person: Person = { name: "nil", age: 30 };
  const handleShowPerson = ({ name, age }: Person) => (
    <h1>
      My name is {name} and I am {age} years old`)
    </h1>
  );
  const data: Data = [person, handleShowPerson];
}
```

Comment: Can we define this as an interface?

Comment: I don't think you can define a `Tuple` as an interface. Any issue with `type`?

Comment: @goodboy you could write `type _Data = [Person, ✂]` and then `interface Data extends _Data {}` but can you explain why you care about the difference between `type` and `interface` here?  Seems like an XY problem

Comment: I have to write like this in a bigger program and this is just a small example to see what I can do to solve this problem. Can you solve this problem?@jcalz

Answer (score 1):

you already have the code for *person* so you just have to annotate your prop with it. Your *handleShowPerson* is function and returns JSX as shown below. Lastly you wanted *data* to be an array so you would have to annotate that too in the interface.

```
interface person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
interface data {
    person: person;
    handleShowPerson: () => JSX.Element;
}
```

Then you can create an array for your data object by simply initialising

`const data: data[] = [{person, handleShowPerson}];`

**Edit**

I think I missunderstood your question. The above answer is if you wanted to have an array which holds multiple tuples of person plus the function. If you just want to have an array that has *any* amount of these two things, but they are not coupled together you can type it as:

```
type Data = Person | ((person: Person) => JSX.Element);
```

and then type your variable like that:

```
const data: Data[] = [person, handleShowPerson];
```

Comment: The problem remains when I use this method, I'll link my code for you to check https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-benji-72t09o?file=/src/App.tsx:130-151